# Terraform postgresql provider fails to create the role and database after the provision in aws

Tags: postgresql, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to provision the postgres in the aws also create the database and roles sequentially using the terraform.
But getting the below exception and i could not able to create the role/db.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    # postgresql = {
    #   source  = "cyrilgdn/postgresql"
    #   version = "1.15.0"
    # }
    postgresql = {
      source = "terraform-providers/postgresql"
      version = ">=1.7.2"
    }

    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = "2.4.1"
    }
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.0.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "database" {
  identifier = "dev-test"

  allocated_storage = 100
  storage_type      = "gp2"
  engine            = "postgres"
  engine_version    = "13.4"
  port              = 5432
  instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
  username                     = "postgres"
  performance_insights_enabled = true
  password                     = "postgres$123"
  db_subnet_group_name         = "some_name"
  vpc_security_group_ids       = ["sg_name"]
  parameter_group_name         = "default.postgres13"
  publicly_accessible          = true
  delete_automated_backups     = false
  storage_encrypted            = true
  tags = {
    Name = "dev-test"
  }
  skip_final_snapshot = true
}

#To create the "raw" database
provider "postgresql" {
  version = ">=1.4.0"
  database         = "raw"
  host             = aws_db_instance.database.address
  port             = aws_db_instance.database.port
  username         = aws_db_instance.database.username
  password         = aws_db_instance.database.password
  sslmode          = "require"
  connect_timeout  = 15
  superuser        = false
  expected_version = aws_db_instance.database.engine_version
}

#creation of the role
resource "postgresql_role" "application_role" {
  provider = postgresql
  name               = "test"
  login              = true
  password           = "test$123"
  encrypted_password = true
  create_database = false
  depends_on         = [aws_db_instance.database]
}
```

Error -

```
Error: dial tcp 18.221.183.66:5432: i/o timeout
│
│   with postgresql_role.application_role,
│   on main.tf line 79, in resource "postgresql_role" "application_role":
│   79: resource "postgresql_role" "application_role" {
│
╵
```

I noticed few people are saying to include the `expected_version` attribute in the latest version should work.
Although including the expected version attribute still the issue persist.
I need to provision the postgres in the aws, create the db and roles.

What could be issue with my script ?

Comment: Was the AWS resource created before you get the error?

Comment: Yes it is created. @Marko E

Comment: What is the security group for the rds? Is it in a public subnet?

Comment: I also have the same issue. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation [1], you are missing the `scheme` in the `postgresql` provider:

```
provider "postgresql" {
  scheme           = "awspostgres"
  database         = "raw"
  host             = aws_db_instance.database.address
  port             = aws_db_instance.database.port
  username         = aws_db_instance.database.username
  password         = aws_db_instance.database.password
  sslmode          = "require"
  connect_timeout  = 15
  superuser        = false
  expected_version = aws_db_instance.database.engine_version
}
```

Additionally, I am not sure if you can use `database = raw` or it has to be `database = "postgres"`, which is the default value so it does not have to be specified.

One other note: I do not think you need to specify the `provider` block in every resource. You just define it once in the `required_providers` block (like you did for `aws` provider) and then anything related to that provider will assume using the provider defined. In other words, you should remove the `version = ">=1.4.0"` from the `provider "postgres"` and `provider = postgresql` from the `resource "postgresql_role" "application_role"` and the code should still work.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs#aws

Comment: Then how do I need to create the new database for the "raw" one? if we are providing the database="postgres"

Comment: Not sure what `raw` is supposed to do as I do not know much about Postgres, but as far as I have looked in the documentation I did not see any reference to the `raw` value.